# Firefox Addon - See which resource sends a http request?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

The Firefox developer tools has a network inspector that lets you view every resource that is loaded by the browser with the request and response headers, but while it sounds simple, it doesn't have the feature to view which resource (html, css, js, flash etc) requests which resource. Is there an addon or anything else that does this?

Ultmately it would be very useful to have a tree-view of all the requests steming off the initial loading of the html.

Comment: This would be a very neat thing to have. I wonder if we can request the moz dev team to add this.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a network analyzer: a tool that show you the network traffic on your pc. You can set up the port or the protocol to analyze and so see the content of requests and responses.

Comment: Wouldn't that just show Firefox as making the request, as opposed to a specific web resource?